# Change VisualState of a VisualElement with Prism, in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism, visualstatemanager

How can I change the VisualState of an element from the Prism ViewModel? 
Is there a Bindable property I can use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the visual state of an element, you can do it from the Code-Behind of a page, like this:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(yourViewElement, yourViewElementState);
```

However, not the best advice, but you can subscribe to changes in your viewmodel, from your code.behind and then invoke the VisualStateManager.

Example

```
YourPage()
{
    viewModel.PropertyChanged += FooChanged;
}

public void FooChanged()
{
     if (!args.PropertyName.Equals("YourProperty"))
     {
          VisualStateManager.GoToState(yourViewElement, yourViewElementState);
     }
        return;
}
```

Comment: thanks but I was looking for a way to do it in the ViewModel without touching the page codebehind

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in this post, adding a Behavior to the XAML page:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/127531/behavior-bindableproperty-not-update